# Can acceleration at a point be non-zero if angular velocity is zero?

Tags: acceleration, velocity, rotational-kinematics, angular-velocity

I have just started studying rotational kinematics.

Comment: If you throw an apple into the air without rotating it, then all points have a non-zero acceleration of $g$, but there's no angular velocity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you progress in your studies of rotational kinematics you will find that for the kinematic equations for constant linear acceleration there are equivalent kinematic equations for constant angular acceleration.

When a ball is thrown up it eventually, at the top of its flight, comes  to rest where its acceleration is still the acceleration of free fall downwards, and then it fall back to Earth.

In the same way a disc which has an angular velocity can be brought to rest with a constant angular acceleration and then start to rotate in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Angular acceleration, i.e. the rate of change of angular velocity can independently be non-zero, and total acceleration is the sum of these perpendicular vectors.